# AdMob ads are not displaying in iPad pro in AppStore version

Tags: ios, iphone, admob, ads

I have implemented AdMob in my iOS app.
The ads were coming without any problem in distribution installers.
After appstore release, I downloaded and installed from Appstore. In one of my device the Ad is not showing. The Ad is shown as just a text in a corner, "Ads by Google(i)"

Can anyone help.

Comment: If its on one device issue, then it may be because of network . Do check once your network speed? Or try using network of suitable bandwidth?

Comment: At the same time, I am getting Ads in another devices. I checked for a long time, upto one day, and the same thing happens. The issue having device is iPad pro.